# How do I use the same XMLAttribute for multiple properties?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the below wrapper class.

```
[Serializable]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public static void Serialize()
        {
            string fileName = "data.xml";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Make, Model & Year");
            var vehicle = new Vehicle
            {
                Make = "Honda",
                Model = "H1245",
                Year = "1975"
            };
            //Serialization
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicle));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            xml.Serialize(writer, vehicle);
            writer.Close();
            //Attribution
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                document.Load(fileName);
                var nodeList = document.SelectNodes("//Vehicle//*");

                var attribute1 = document.CreateAttribute("applicableTo");
                attribute1.Value = "Common";
                var attribute2 = document.CreateAttribute("applicableTo");
                attribute2.Value = "Cfpd";
                var attribute3 = document.CreateAttribute("applicableTo");
                attribute3.Value = "Markel";

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (nodeList[i].InnerText.Equals("Honda"))
                        ((XmlElement)(nodeList[i])).SetAttributeNode(attribute1);
                    if (nodeList[i].InnerText.Equals("H1245"))
                        ((XmlElement)(nodeList[i])).SetAttributeNode(attribute2);
                    if (nodeList[i].InnerText.Equals("1975"))
                        ((XmlElement)(nodeList[i])).SetAttributeNode(attribute3);
                }
                document.Save(Console.Out);
            }
        }
```

My desired output is as below. However, I get the same output as XML as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Vehicle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Make applicableTo="Common">Honda</Make>
  <Model applicableTo="Cfpd">H1245</Model>
  <Year applicableTo="Markel">1975</Year>
</Vehicle>
```

Here goes my problem,

How do I have the attribute `applicableTo` set to Make, Model and Year properties without having to create them like `attribute1`, `attribute2`, `attribute3` yet values to be assigned based on the input assigned to properties? Which means, if `Make` is `Honda` the XML output should be `<Make applicableTo="Common">Honda</Make>` and likewise.

XMLAttribute can only be set to one property in a class, which is not ideal when dealing with huge number of classes. And so `SetAttributeNode` throws error -

```
The 'Attribute' node cannot be inserted because it is already an attribute of another element.
```

Please help.

> Please note that the format of my output shouldn't change.

Comment: *My desired output is as below. However, I get the same output as XML as below.* -- what?  Are you getting the output you want, or not?

Comment: Seems another [eerily similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64431164/3791245) was asked today.  Homework maybe?  Full disclosure: I gave that question an answer.  But now, when combining how both questions were asked, I can't figure out if my answer was even helpful or not. :(

Comment: Thanks @SeanSkelly for the answer in the link, that was helpful. Although other solution I tried was to create multiple classes for each property, it was rejected by the interviewer as it is not useful if there are more than 100s of properties. So I came up with what I have in the OP, and I don't know yet if it is accepted. Your answer in the link is perfect when I had to use the XmlSerializer. The question asked in my interview was vague, I was not told if the attribute values are static or are assigned based on user input. Thanks again.

Comment: @dbc I have the desired output, I wanted to know if there are any other ways to implement this, I am really new to C# and stackoverflow so I'm sorry if I'm being rude. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Make", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Make Attribute", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Model", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Model Attribute", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Year Attribute", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Honda", "Common", "H1245", "Cfpd", "1975", "Markel" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Honda", "Common", "H1245", "Cfpd", "1975", "Markel" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Honda", "Common", "H1245", "Cfpd", "1975", "Markel" });
            Vehicle.Serialize(dt, FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public static void Serialize(DataTable dt, string fileName)
        {
            string ident = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<Vehicles xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                "</Vehicles>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement xVehicles = doc.Root;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement xVehicle = new XElement("Vehicle", new object[] {
                    new XElement("Make", new object[] {new XAttribute("applicableTo", row.Field<string>("Make Attribute")), row.Field<string>("Make")}),
                    new XElement("Make", new object[] {new XAttribute("applicableTo", row.Field<string>("Model Attribute")), row.Field<string>("Model")}),
                    new XElement("Make", new object[] {new XAttribute("applicableTo", row.Field<string>("Year Attribute")), row.Field<string>("Year")})
                });
                xVehicles.Add(xVehicle);
            }
            doc.Save(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```